# Directory not found for option '-L/.../AppAuth'

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, appauth

I am getting this error for every search path in my Library Search Paths. Deleting all library search paths does get rid of the error but I need them. App auth is the first warning I get.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth'
```

Which results in the error

```
ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
lang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now when I go to the path above, App Auth is indeed NOT there. I am pod installing in my ios directory.

`${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppAuth` is added to my Library search paths.

What else can I do? If more information is needed, ask and I will provide it!

Comment: Were you using appAuth from Firebase? And now you no longer need the AppAuth?? To remove the AppAuth, you can go to your pod file, and remove the AppAuth then pod install again.
target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AppAuth', '~> version' /// remove this one if there is a line like this
end

Comment: No. I do not wish to remove AppAuth

Comment: Are you working with someone within one project? Did anyone from your team just update the podfile?

Comment: That is from a fresh pod install

Comment: Since it's a fresh pod install, you will need to use `. xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj`. Because after `pod install`, your project get configured in `.xcworkspace`. Please try to open <Your_project_name>.xcworkspace and re-compile

Comment: Unfortunately I am indeed using the .xcworkspace file

Comment: Yes! Sorry I forgot to add that piece of information. I did indeed remove a chunk and replace it with 'the three dots. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: So the output is huge. But it looks like the only AppAuth is only found in the ios directory of my project. ```/Users/user/project name/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth``` and also in ```/Users/user/project name/ios/Pods/AppAuth
``` and lastly here ```/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project name-bunch of letters /Index/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth```

Comment: Try changing to `-L/Users/user/project name/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth` and make sure the spacing and capital/lower casing is identical.

Comment: Will do boss, gonna try after my meeting. Thank you for your time!